# Is the cheese used in PizzaHut and at Dominos in Malaysia vegetarian?

Tags: vegetarian-diet, dairy-products, restaurant, is-it-vegetarian, lacto-vegetarianism

Both of these big food chains provide vegetarian pizzas in most of the country, but is the cheese used in their pizza free from animal enzyme?

Comment: I'm from Malaysia, so I prefer to know how its done down here

Comment: The only way to know that would be to ask them for a list of ingredients and check that it has "non animal rennet"

Comment: If the question is specifically about a source/vendor/chain etc. (and not a general question like: "how to find out if …"), I think it would be better to only ask about one of them per question post. Otherwise answerers could only answer the question fully if they know about *all* sources, which is of of course not necessarily the case.

Comment: Usually anything processed is far from being vegetarian unless marked on the menu as so. Too many ingredients gone wrong. Most cheese toppings arent often cheese at all. It you want to be veg, you better prepared to do your research.

Comment: Also FYI some items at Pizza Hut (some wings and salad dressings and several desserts) are made with eggs. Is that a concern?

Answer (score 2):

Where I worked they used grated part-skim milk mozzarella. Obviously I can't remember the ingridients of the supplier but pricey mozarella's don't have enzymes whereas cheap mozzarella has enzymes.

I have never been to Malaysia (using logic - they should use the same business tactics as part of their brand), but with my experience from working in Dominos I can state that this type of business tries to save money by cutting the quality of everything - from workers rights to the food itself.

Bear in mind that bread can also have animal derived products (including dough). Here is a comprehensive list to watch out for: http://www.ruf.rice.edu/~veggie/nonveg/watch_out.html

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question -- while they might be using the most inexpensive cheese available, is that with or without animal rennet? (And your second paragraph is even more tangential.) Could you [edit] to more directly respond to what the original poster was asking about?